# Проблема с проверкой нулевого массива Js

Tags: javascript, css, массивы, веб-программирование, frontend

Есть карточки с вопросами, при нажатии на кнопку согласен происходит пролистывание вперед, при нажатии не согласен происходит переворачивание карточки. Чтобы перейти на следующий вопрос надо нажать далее на этой карточке. При ответе на последнюю карточку должная появляться кнопка. Я делаю проверку массива на пустоту, если в массиве не осталось карточек, то можно показывать кнопку. Проблема в том, что так работает при нажатии на кнопку согласен. При нажатии на не согласен класс к кнопке не присваивается

```js
'use strict';

var quizcardContainer = document.querySelector('.quizcard');
var allCards = document.querySelectorAll('.flip-card');
var nope = document.getElementById('nope');
var love = document.getElementById('love');
var next = document.getElementById('next');
var quizcardbuttons = document.querySelectorAll('quizcard--buttons');
var arrow = document.getElementsByClassName('arrownext');


function initCards(card, index) {
  var newCards = document.querySelectorAll('.flip-card:not(.removed)');

  newCards.forEach(function (card, index) {
    card.style.zIndex = allCards.length - index;
    card.style.opacity = (10 - index) / 10;
  });
  
  quizcardContainer.classList.add('loaded');
}

initCards();

function createButtonListener(love) {
  return function (event) {
    var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.flip-card:not(.removed)');
    var next = document.querySelectorAll('.next:not(.removed)');

    if (!cards.length) document.getElementsByClassName('arrownext')[0].classList.remove('invisible');

    var card = cards[0];
    var nextbutton = next[0];

    card.classList.add('removed');
    nextbutton.classList.add('removed');

    if (love) {
      card.style.zIndex = 1000000000000000000;
      card.style.transform = 'translate(100vw, -100px) rotate(-30deg)';
      cards[1].classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {
      card.classList.toggle('do-flip');
      card.style.zIndex = 1000000000000000000;
        document.getElementById('nope').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('love').style.visibility = 'hidden';

      nextbutton.onclick = function() {
        card.style.zIndex = 1000000000000000000;
        card.style.transform = 'translate(-100vw, -100px) rotate(30deg) rotateY(-180deg)';
        cards[1].classList.remove('hidden');
        document.getElementById('nope').style.visibility = 'visible';
          document.getElementById('love').style.visibility = 'visible';
          if (!cards.length) document.getElementsByClassName('arrownext')[0].classList.remove('invisible');
  };

    }
    
    initCards();
    event.preventDefault();
  };
}



var nopeListener = createButtonListener(false);
var loveListener = createButtonListener(true);

nope.addEventListener('click', nopeListener);
love.addEventListener('click', loveListener);
```

```css
.invisible {
  display: none;
}

.quizcard {
  height: 525px;
  width: 850px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -moz-transform: perspective(1800px);
  -webkit-perspective: 1800px;
  perspective: 1800px;
  background: transparent;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.loaded.quizcard {
  opacity: 1;
}

.quizcard--cards {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex-grow: 2;
  text-align: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
  z-index: 1;
}

.quizcard--buttons {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.flip-card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 900px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: absolute;
  -o-transition: transform 0.5s ease-out, opacity 0.2s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s ease-out, opacity 0.2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: transform 0.5s ease-out, opacity 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-out, opacity 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  will-change: transform;
  right: 0;
}

.dont-flip {
  -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.do-flip {
  -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.flip-card .flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  background: transparent;
  color: #000;
  padding: 20px 40px;
}

.flip-card .flip-card-front {
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.flip-card .flip-card-back {
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  height: 100%;
}

.card::after, .card::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.4rem;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 670px;
  height: 320px;
  right: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


.face_text {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
}

.back_text {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.middle p:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #FF882A;
  color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #FF882A;
  background: white;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  bottom: -7px;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  padding: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nope {
  background: red;
}

.yes {
  background: green;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.arrownext {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  bottom: -7px;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  padding: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 50px;
}

.button__select::after, .button__select::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.button__select {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: #FFF;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  background: #FF882A;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  height: 49px;
  width: 162px;
  margin-left: 70px;
}
.button__select::before {
  bottom: -5px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 162px;
  left: 5px;
  background: #FFF;
}
.button__select::after {
  right: -5px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  background: #FFF;
}
.button__select:active {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.button__select:active::before {
  bottom: -5px;
  height: 5px;
  left: 3px;
}
.button__select:active::after {
  right: -5px;
  width: 5px;
  bottom: -3px;
}

.button__next::after, .button__next::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.button__next {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: #FF882A;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  background: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  height: 38px;
  width: 135px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #FF882A;
  font-size: 1rem;

}
.button__next::before {
  bottom: -5px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 130px;
  left: 2px;
  background: #FF882A;
}
.button__next::after {
  right: -5px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  background: #FF882A;
}
.button__next:active {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.button__next:active::before {
  bottom: -5px;
  height: 5px;
  left: 3px;
}
.button__next:active::after {
  right: -5px;
  width: 5px;
  bottom: -3px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="quizcard">
  <div class="quizcard--cards">
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="flip-card-front">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="middle">
              <p class="face_text">Вопрос</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="middle">
            <p class="back_text">Ответ</p>
          </div>
          <button class="button__next next">Далее</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="flip-card hidden">
      <div class="flip-card-front">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="inner">
            <div class="middle">
              <p class="face_text">Вопрос</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="middle">
            <p class="back_text"Ответ</p>
          </div>
          <button class="button__next next">Далее</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="flip-card hidden">
      <div class="flip-card-front">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="inner">
            <div class="middle">
              <p class="face_text">Вопрос</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="middle">
            <p class="back_text">Ответ</p>
          </div>
          <button class="button__next next">Далее</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="quizcard--buttons">
    <button class="nope button__select" id="nope">Не согласен</button>
    <button class="yes button__select"  id="love">Согласен</button>
  </div>
```

. В чем проблема?

Comment: А где у вас кнопка с классом `arrownext`?

Comment: Пожалуйста если мой ответ вам помог, то примите его как "Правильный ответ", нажав на галочку слева от ответа :)

Answer (score 0):

Я не очень понимаю, что вам нужно, что за `arrownext`, но попробую помочь вам показав пример:

```js
var questions = ["Вопрос1", "Вопрос2", "Вопрос3", "Вопрос4"];
var love = document.getElementById('love');
var nope = document.getElementById('nope');
var currentQuestion = 0;
var htmlQuest = document.getElementsByClassName('face_text')[0];

function swapCard(){
        ++currentQuestion;
        if(currentQuestion >= questions.length){
            love.style.visibility = "hidden";
        nope.style.visibility = "hidden";
        htmlQuest.innerHTML = "";
        currentQuestion = questions.length;
        return;
    }
    htmlQuest.innerHTML = questions[currentQuestion];
}

window.onload = function() {
    htmlQuest.innerHTML = questions[currentQuestion];
};
```

```css
.invisible {
  display: none;
}

.quizcard {
  height: 525px;
  width: 850px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -moz-transform: perspective(1800px);
  -webkit-perspective: 1800px;
  perspective: 1800px;
  background: transparent;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.loaded.quizcard {
  opacity: 1;
}

.quizcard--cards {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex-grow: 2;
  text-align: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
  z-index: 1;
}

.quizcard--buttons {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.flip-card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 900px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: absolute;
  -o-transition: transform 0.5s ease-out, opacity 0.2s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s ease-out, opacity 0.2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: transform 0.5s ease-out, opacity 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-out, opacity 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  will-change: transform;
  right: 0;
}

.dont-flip {
  -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.do-flip {
  -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.flip-card .flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  background: transparent;
  color: #000;
  padding: 20px 40px;
}

.flip-card .flip-card-front {
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.flip-card .flip-card-back {
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  height: 100%;
}

.card::after, .card::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.4rem;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 670px;
  height: 320px;
  right: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


.face_text {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
}

.back_text {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.middle p:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #FF882A;
  color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #FF882A;
  background: white;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  bottom: -7px;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  padding: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nope {
  background: red;
}

.yes {
  background: green;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.arrownext {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  bottom: -7px;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  padding: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 50px;
}

.button__select::after, .button__select::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.button__select {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: #FFF;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  background: #FF882A;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  height: 49px;
  width: 162px;
  margin-left: 70px;
}
.button__select::before {
  bottom: -5px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 162px;
  left: 5px;
  background: #FFF;
}
.button__select::after {
  right: -5px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  background: #FFF;
}
.button__select:active {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.button__select:active::before {
  bottom: -5px;
  height: 5px;
  left: 3px;
}
.button__select:active::after {
  right: -5px;
  width: 5px;
  bottom: -3px;
}

.button__next::after, .button__next::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.button__next {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: #FF882A;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  background: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  height: 38px;
  width: 135px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #FF882A;
  font-size: 1rem;

}
.button__next::before {
  bottom: -5px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 130px;
  left: 2px;
  background: #FF882A;
}
.button__next::after {
  right: -5px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  background: #FF882A;
}
.button__next:active {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.button__next:active::before {
  bottom: -5px;
  height: 5px;
  left: 3px;
}
.button__next:active::after {
  right: -5px;
  width: 5px;
  bottom: -3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="quizcard">
  <div class="quizcard--cards">
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="flip-card-front">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="middle">
              <p class="face_text"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
    <div class="quizcard--buttons">
    <button class="nope button__select" id="nope" onclick="swapCard()">Не согласен</button>
    <button class="yes button__select"  id="love" onclick="swapCard()">Согласен</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Идея в том, чтобы хранить в массиве `questions` сами вопросы, а не в `html`. Так же можно родительскому классу (который отвечает за сам блок вопроса, например `flip-card`) присваивать какую нибудь анимацию, чтобы вопросы появлялись плавно например.

Если есть вопросы, можете задать в комментариях :)